# transparent background only

Tags: html, css, prototypejs

I have a div which contains a header and a form.

It floats over other elements and I would like to make it's background transparent.

I can't figure out how to make the background transparent while keeping the input fields, and text fully opaque.

I have tried the following:

```
var control = $("myControlDiv");
control .show();

control .setStyle({opacity:"0.60", filter:"alpha(opacity=60)"});
var children = control .childElements;

for (var i = 0 ; i < children.length; i++)
    children[i].setStyle({opacity:"1.00", filter:"alpha(opacity=100)"});
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the background, not the opacity.

There are various approaches you can take. The more efficient ones have the poorest browser support. This article describes [how to implement them in a backwards compatible fashion](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, for all the browsers besides IE you can use the CSS 3 rgba, that sets the color and the alpha, but only for the background (if you set it on background-color, of course). For example, this is how 60% transparent black background color will look in CSS:

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
```

For IE it is more complicated, but there is a great guide for it:
http://www.daltonlp.com/view/217

Answer (score 1):

Create a single-pixel PNG with a transparency of 60% (or however much). Set that as your background image.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a div around the form.

`<div style="background:transparent;height:300px;width:300px;"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The way to work around this is to make the outer div relatively positioned and the inner div  absolutely positioned. This will allow the inner div to have a different opacity then the outer div. You can check the below link and demo.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

demo page
http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/css-opacity/css-opacity-demo.html

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can do this is:

a)  Use CSS3, similar to Cokegod's post, which is extremely limiting in terms of demographics, etc.

b) Create a div that houses your content, place your background div within that and apply your opacity setting to the background-layer.  Because the opacity/filter is for the entire element, creating a "background" div allows for the opacity to be applied and the container to remain unaffected.  It's a little bit of a pain, but it works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: opacity sets the translucency of the final rendered element and all its descendants — so that won't work

Comment: It does work.  I've built it this way.  And it's really simple, if you're applying the opacity to the background element.  Check my post before docking a comment, as you'll notice I said create a background div within your container div.